# On Windows with Winrun4j how do I specify Java gclog location that understands APPDATA location

Tags: java, windows, winrun4j

I want to enable garbage collection logging for Java application running on Windows

Like standard Windows programs the application is installed in C:/Program Files/*CompanyName*/*SoftwareName* and my application logs are stored in C:/Users/*username*/Roaming/*SoftwareName*

and in my code I identify the location of C:/Users/*username*/AppData with

```
System.getenv("APPDATA");
```

Now I want the garbage logs to also go in that location, but I cannot see how I could specify that.

Also problematically if i just specify a filename and try to create in C:/Program Files/*CompanyName*/*SoftwareName* instead with

```
-Xlog:gc*:file=gc.log:time:filecount=7,filesize=8M
```

then JVM fails to start because on Windows programs do not have permissions to create files in this folder after installation

Now if i was starting application in a batch script I suppose I could use `%APPDATA%` in the batch but I am using `winrun4j` so I do not see I have access to such variables from the .ini file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found I could use %APPDATA% in the .ini file as well

e.g

```
vmarg.1=-Xlog:gc*:file=%APPDATA%\SoftwareName\Logs\gc.log:time:filecount=7,filesize=2M
```